# Django - Check if reverse foreign key relation exists

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following database structure:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    @property
    def type(self):
        if getattr(self, 'typeA', None):
            return 'typeA'
        elif getattr(self, 'typeB', None):
            return 'typeB'
        elif getattr(self, 'typeC', None):
            return 'typeC'

    @property
    def profile(self):
        return getattr(self, self.type)


class TypeA(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    # -- up to field 5 --


class TypeB(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    field6 = ...
    field7 = ...
    # -- up to field 10


class TypeC(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    field11 = ...
    field12 = ...
    # -- up to field 22
```

I have three different types of profiles: Type A, Type B and Type C, all of them having different fields from each other.
Up until now if i wanted to do a reverse `OneToOneField` lookup from `User` to one of the profile types, i'd have a `@property` which returned the type of profile that the user has. And then i'd have another `@property` which returns the instance of that profile type.

The problem with this approach is that when i call `user.profile`, up to 3 queries are made to the database in order to return the correct profile type. I want to reduce this to just 1 query in all cases.

I looked on the internet on how to make a field on the model `User` called `profile` which will hold either of those 3 profile types. Stomped upon `GenericForeignKeys` but in my case it will just make my code uglier and i think i complicate it too much by using them.

My final idea is to the `User` model in the following way:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    TYPES = (
        ('typeA', 'typeA'),
        ('typeB', 'typeB'),
        ('typeC', 'typeC')
    )

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    type = CharField(choices=TYPES)

    @property
    def profile(self):
        return getattr(self, self.type)
```

My question, is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `.select_related(..)` to fetch the types *together* with the user, so you fetch this with `User.objects.select_related('typea', 'typeb', 'typec').get(pk=user-pk)` (with `user-pk` the primary key of the user you fetch).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh yeah good idea actually. But when i just need a single user i think that i'll stick to making 3 queries, because otherwise all the users are fetched, increasing the query time. And when i'd need multiple users, i'd use `select_related`. Hmm kinda makes me think if i should just stick to adding another field `type` on the user model, since it will make things easier huh, what do you think?

Comment: no `.select_related` works on the *same* query, so it will "piggyback" on the query to fetch the user, and in the same time fetch the ones for `typea`, `typeb` and `typec` with a `JOIN`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Mhm, about the JOIN part i know. Therefore you say that it won't slow down the query at all in both cases (1 user and multiple users) ?

Comment: it will slightly slow down that *single* query, but since we make one query, it will be faster than making four queries as is the case here. A database has index structures on foreign keys, to make the JOIN process quite efficient.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ahh, tough choice then. Either `.select_related` or an additional database field. Kind of hard to decide but i'll see myself from now on. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you don't need an extra database field normally. Django can also query in reverse, so you can use `.select_related('typea', 'typeb', 'typec')` with the current modeling.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem established that i'll go with `.select_related`. thanks again.